# Doubt regarding properties of open sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am studying Metric Spaces from the book by Satish Shirali and H. L. Vasudeva. The chapter on **Topology of Metric Spaces** talks about a certain property about the union of open sets. It states:

> The union of any finite, countable or uncountable family of open sets is open but the intersection of an infinite number of open sets need not be open.

What exactly is meant by the phrase **"finite, countable or uncountable"** ?

Comment: If you haven’t studied countable infinities and uncountable infinities, just take this statement to mean that the union of any collection of open sets is open, but an infinite intersect of open sets need not be open.

Comment: Given any collection of open sets, no matter how big or small that collection maybe, that is, finite, countable, or uncountable, their union is open, but their intersection is not necessarily open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a long way of saying that the union of *any* family $\mathcal F$ of open sets is still an open set. Note that $\mathcal F$ may be finite, countable or uncountable.